# Altering panel dismiss size with multiple different sized panels

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I Have five panels that i use in a web application that I have written. One of the panels needs to be slightly larger due to the amount of information it contains.

However clicking closer to the edge of that dismisses the panel. I know i can alter the width and start point on the ui-panel-dismiss class but how can i do this just for that one panel. I cant see any differentiating classes between that and the other panel dismiss. And i don't want to have a gap on the other panels. The only way i can think of doing it would be using jquery to alter the panel width programmatically.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<div id="panel2" data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
    <a href= "#" data-rel="close" data-role="button">Close</a>
     <div id="colourChange"></div>    
</div>

css: 
#panel2 {
    width: 25em;    
}
```

**EDIT:** Added JSfiddle showing what i mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/awm1475a/

Clicking the blue div in the panel 2 should trigger colour change instead it closes the panel

Comment: Please show relevant markup/CSS/script and possible create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I added the JSfiddle showing my problem

Comment: Thank you. Although both answers worked well. I marked this correct as it seems a more sensible way to do this and is extensible if i create more panels in future

Comment: you can upvote both answers if you find them helpful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of dismissible overlay that overlaps with panel. That overlay closes the panel when its clicked. So you need to adjust its width as you did to the panel itself.

A quick fix is to use [`panelopen`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-open) to add new width to that overlay. Check this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhju7645/).

```
$(document).on("panelopen", ".ui-panel", function () {
    var panel = $(this).width(),
        screen = $(window).width(),
        width = screen - panel;
    $(".ui-panel-dismiss").width(width);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick hack to get you around the issue.  Simply raise panel2 z-index higher that the dismiss div. By default, the panel has a z-index of 1001 and the dismiss div has 1002.

```
#panel2 {
    width: 25em;  
    z-index: 1003;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/awm1475a/1/)**